# Conditionally run a test case if first test case is passed or failed - jest

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, enzyme, testcase

I have a method `updateHeight()` in a class based component that updates arrows height based on image height. when there are no arrows then it returns `false`.

I want to write a test case that checks if an arrow exists and then function should not return false and Vice versa.

e.g;

```
let arrows expect(wrapper.find('.arrow').length).toBe(1);
if ( arrows ) {
    // run second test case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that worked for me. Still, I don't know if its this is the way it should be. Need suggestion in the comment.

```
describe( '>> update arrows testing', () => {

  // set variable to false by default
  let arrowsExists = false;

  // check if arrows exist and set the variable to true
  test( 'Check if Arrows Exist', () => {
    const wrapper = mount( <Component/> );
    expect( wrapper.find('.playlist-slider .slick-arrow').length).toBe(1);
    // set the variable to true
    arrowsExists = true;
  } );

  // test update arrow height function if arrows exist
  test( 'Update Arrow Height Func test', () => {
    const wrapper = Shallow( <Component/> );

    if ( arrowsExists ) {
      // function should update height and return true.
      expect(wrapper.instance().updateArrowHeight()).toEqual(true);
    }

  } );

} );
```